# Can there be more photos in the Stack Exchange store?

Tags: feature-request, shop

The new [Stack Exchange store](http://shop.stackexchange.com/) looks nice, but the products (especially the [hoodie](http://shop.stackexchange.com/products/stack-exchange-hoodie) and [jacket](http://shop.stackexchange.com/collections/frontpage/products/stack-overflow-jacket-1)) can use more (and larger) photos.

Comment: At least get some cadavers

Comment: +1 - That might also help with sizing .. E.g. "Pictured: Medium". I'm contemplating a jacket for an upcoming trip and I'm not sure if I should go L or XL.

Comment: Where's my button to vote up or down items in the store? What if I need to say something like "-1, would not buy again, sharpie ruined my pristine whiteboard" or "+1, hoodie got me a free space shuttle ride"?

Comment: Is this store operational yet?

Comment: @George: It looks like it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We'll be adding more (and special) photos as we go on.  We're currently in process of getting it all up and running so everyone can get their Swag but we'll be constantly iterating once its fully going.